# Does Azure Application Insights supports monitoring for wide range of enterprise application like SAP,JAVA, OR COTS PRODUCTS

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Does Azure Application Insights supports monitoring for wide range of enterprise application like SAP,JAVA, OR  other COTS PRODUCTS. If no then which application monitoring tool should be considered which supports basic monitoring for wide range of enterprise applications

Comment: I suggest to keep just first sentence from your question. The other part is too general " If no then w..". Please remove it. If needed try to focus on some specific topics in other question.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [official list of supported platforms/languages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/platforms).

Comment: Hi Thanks for sharing this. This list doesn't include Sap or any other enterprise application. So are they supported?

Comment: Calls to SAP are not auto-discovered. But it is straightforward to wrap call to any dependency and then report data through one of Track methods. This will light up all scenarios (metrics, application map, distributed tracing, logs, alerts, etc.)